# Write binary stream to browser using PHP

Tags: java, php, jasper-reports, fopen, php-java-bridge

**Background**

Trying to stream a PDF report written using iReport through PHP to the browser. The general problem is: how do you write binary data to the browser using PHP?

**Working Code**

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache private');
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment, filename=climate-report.pdf');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

$path = realpath( "." ) . "/output.pdf";

$em = java('net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager');
$result = $em->exportReportToPdf($pm);
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen( $result ) );

$fh = fopen( $path, 'w' );
fwrite( $fh, $result );
fclose( $fh );

readfile( $path );
```

**Non-working Code**

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache private');
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment, filename=climate-report.pdf');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

$path = realpath( "." ) . "/output.pdf";

$em = java('net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager');
$result = $em->exportReportToPdf($pm);
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen( $result ) );

echo $result;
```

**Question**

How can I take out the middle step of writing to the file and write directly to the browser so that the PDF is not corrupted?

**Update**

PDF file sizes:

- Working: 594778 bytes
- Non-working: 1059365 bytes

Thank you!

Comment: Does adding all the headers that you cut out from the first work?

Comment: @Casey: The headers have always been the same in both cases. See the revised problem.

Comment: Ahh that's climate report! No worry, that's normal. They're always *buggy* ;)

Comment: We echo binary data all the time so that can't be your problem. Where did you get the PDF file sizes, from "Content-Length"?

Comment: @ZZ: By saving both files to disk and then running `ls`.

Comment: Do the content-length headers match on the requests? They should, due to the fact the code is identical up until there. I just tried this reading from a file and echoing the binary data directly (not using readfile()) and it worked fine. strlen also produced the correct length (identical to filesize()).

Comment: @DaveJarvis, since you are writing to `/output.pdf`, wouldn't 2 concurrent users corrode each others data? How do you overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've previously experienced problems writing from Java because it'll use UTF-16. The function `outputPDF` from http://zeronine.org/lab/index.php uses `java_set_file_encoding("ISO-8859-1");`. Thus:

```
  java_set_file_encoding("ISO-8859-1");

  $em = java('net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager');
  $result = $em->exportReportToPdf($pm);

  header('Content-Length: ' . strlen( $result ) );

  echo $result;
```

Comment: You're right. Sorry I didn't try it. in Any case, I did try your code with a PDF red via file_get_contents and echo works without a problem.

The only thing that rings a bell here is (I think) the mix of Java and PHP. I've previously experienced problems writing from Java because it'll use UTF-16 thus inserting a lot of noise/air in the string. Perhaps, writing to a file eliminates this encoding and this explains the differences in sizes and why it doesn't work if you do it directly.
I don't have a PHP-Java bridge installes so sorry I can't provide more insights.

Comment: Hey... actually googling around I think this may be it.
CHeck this out:
http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.pdf-utf16-to-utf8.php

Comment: Even more (sorry... keep finding good stuff in Google once you have a clue of what to look for):
Check this:
http://zeronine.org/lab/index.php/Using_Jasper_report_with_PHP

Particularly the function called outputPDF. It uses
java_set_file_encoding("ISO-8859-1");
and then some additional magic :)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You just write the output. Make sure that:

- correct headers have been set
- no other character have been accidentally printed before or after the binary (this includes whitespace).

Comment: The headers look correct to me. No other characters have been written.

Comment: And be aware of accidental newlines. This happens with newlines after ?> in include files.